# Realtec HD Graphics 3000 on Dell Laptop windows 10 version 1803

Tags: windows-10

I have tried to uninstall the driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000. It doesn't work, still there.  My screen has become better.  Do I need to worry about this?

Comment: There are no WIn10 drivers for the HD 3000 it's no longer supported, so you need to clarify what you did & what you actually need help with. Aside from that... if it works, you got away with it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the problem? What doesn't work, the graphics or uninstalling the driver? How was your screen bad beforehand and how has it become better?

Comment: Windows 7 display drivers will NOT work due to the differences in the WDDM that Windows 10 supports.  Just figured I would mention that.

Answer (score 0):

There are no drivers published for the Intel HD 3000 for Windows 10.

Drivers written for earlier versions of Windows will NOT work with Windows 10.

The only solution is to allow Windows to automatically detect the device and use its generic drivers to communicate with the device. This should be sufficient for basic computer use, but things such as 3D acceleration and some video formats will not work well or at all.